# . Symbol Breaks Routing

Tags: c#, routes

Currently scratching my head as to why routing to one of my functions is failing.

The route is defined via an attribute:

```
    [Route("emails/{emailAddress}")]
    [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, null, typeof(EmailResponse))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmail(string emailAddress)
```

This works fine if I pass in normal text, i.e. "abc". It hits the route as expected. If I pass in an actual email address: "abc@example.com", I get a 404 back and the endpoint is not hit. It seems that the . symbol is breaking the pattern matching and I have no idea why currently.

I've tried a bunch of different things, including adding RouteDebugger, changed the parameter type to object instead of a string, but nothing seems to work and I haven't been able to track down any clues as to why.

Edit:

Seems that enclosing my parameter in / works. So if the URL ends up being

email/test@email.com/
it works

vs

email/test@email.com

which does not work.

Still have no idea what is actually causing this problem though.

Comment: Are you sure it's the `.` character and not the `@` character?  Are you URL-encoding the value being used in the URL?

Comment: It's definitely the . character. I can submit just an @ symbol and it hits the endpoint, if I do that with a . it doesn't. Additionally, I've found that if I enclose my parameter in '/', it'll match correctly. 

i.e. "emails/{emailAddress}/"

Comment: I would be really hesitated to send email addresses accross the net in a query.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net core for such things I use asterisk (`*`) before the route parameter, by this way you can pass any special character into the route

```cs
[Route("emails/{*emailAddress}")] //added *
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, null, typeof(EmailResponse))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmail(string emailAddress)
```

But note when you are using `*` it can't possible to add another route parameter after `*` for example

This isn't work

```cs
[Route("emails/{*emailAddress}/{anther}")]
```

But this is ok:

```cs
[Route("emails/{other}/{*emailAddress}")]
```